# How to get name of playlist selected in MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

```
    MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    NSArray *playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];
    for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists) {
        NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
        NSArray *songs = [playlist items];
        for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
            NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
            NSLog (@"\t\t%@", songTitle);
        }
    }
```

This code only provides the names of all the palylist's and the songs but I want to get the name of the playlist from which the user has selected the songs from.